# css dialox box to html li item

Tags: css, tooltip, html-lists

how can I have kinda like dialog boxes besite the bullet of a li element?

```
  <div class="contentContenedor">
   <div class="tituloContentContenedor">Box: Promociones nacionales</div>
   <div class="linksContentContenedor">
       <ul>
          <li>
             <span>Vuela barato por Chile</span> 
             <span class="linksContentContenedorClicks" style="background-color:blue; color:white; float:right; padding:0px 4px 0px 4px">612</span>
         </li>
          <li>
             <span>Encántate con el sur de nuestro país</span> 
             <span class="linksContentContenedorClicks" style="background-color:blue; color:white; float:right; padding:0px 4px 0px 4px">102</span>
         </li>
          <li>
             <span>Disfruta el norte de Chile</span> 
             <span class="linksContentContenedorClicks" style="background-color:blue; color:white; float:right; padding:0px 4px 0px 4px">64</span>
         </li>
          <li>
             <span>Canjea tus kms. y vuela por Chile</span> 
             <span class="linksContentContenedorClicks" style="background-color:blue; color:white; float:right; padding:0px 4px 0px 4px">49</span>
         </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

(I can change de order of the span, or put the info outside the li)

CSS:

```
.contentContenedor{
    background-image:url('img/fondo_cajas_home.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center bottom; 
    width:270px;
    height:140px;

}
.tituloContentContenedor{
    background-image:url('img/fondo_tit_cajas_home_270_23.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:270px;
    height:23px;
    color:white;
    font:bold 11px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    padding:6px 0px 2px 11px;
}
.linksContentContenedor{
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#0267C3;
}
.linksContentContenedor ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    margin-left:28px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
.linksContentContenedor li span{
    position:relative;
    left:-5px;
}
.linksContentContenedorClicks{
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
}
```

I'm able tu add a square with info beside de li element but it stays inside de container.

I'd like it to be like:

[image: a busy cat]

but for each li element and always pointing to the bullet.
what complicates me the most is that im not able to get the info outside the container.
if I add absolute position then I wouldnt know the left and top margins since, this boxes are php created.

PS: it is not a tooltip, kinda looks like it but it has to be always present, not when hovering or whatever.

thsnk youuu!

Comment: Please post the CSS you're using, that fails. It helps to see where you're starting from.

Comment: Hmm, here is a way to do it but im sure there are many better ways.. [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/J7KR4/)

Comment: @Ruddy it fails with different text sizes. but thats the idea of what im trying to accomplish

Comment: @gepex It would fail with different font sizes, look how close they are together. Will you be changing the font size after it has been set?

Comment: @ruddy I mean the text1 if its longer the info moves, I wanted to be frozen beside the bullet.

Comment: I cant think of a way to do it.. You can try making your own list.. No idea if this will work for you but its an idea. [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/J7KR4/9/) (I have no idea if this is a terrible way to do stuff like this, so bare that in mind)

Comment: Here is a starting fiddle for you, http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/QVgEd/.

Comment: @JoshPowell Ah very nice. Good work, I was coming up with all sorts of crazy stuff.

Comment: Why thank you :] I see that! I wouldn't say the option you did was bad or anything just unique :p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did,

```
.info {
    position: absolute;
    right: 115%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #c1c1c1;
    text-align: center;
}

.info:before {
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    border-left: 15px solid #c1c1c1;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

This css will make the "info box" you are looking for. This is just a start so you can tweek it in anyway you want. If you are looking for just a border and not solid color then I would advice you to use an image. It could be possible I believe but not very effect/supported.

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/QVgEd/) with the rest of css. Just make sure the `li` containing the `.info` is `position: realtive;`.

Comment: thank you workks, perfect... the ONLY thing is that when the word is too long and break to a second line, the .info:before point to the second line and doest stay pointing the bullet.

Comment: Hey mate, when I get home form work I will look into a fix for that!

Comment: I was able to and I didn't find a good solution. My best idea for you to try is using an `svg`(scalable vector graphic) for the info tags.